# celery not getting tasks from Django Admin Periodic Tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

Using celery 3.1.25 with Django 1.10

I can get celery to run tasks by manually getting into the shell and manually launching the tasks. However when I set a task from the django/admin/PeriodicTasks (run every minute), these tasks are not picked up by celery.

I'm using flower to check the status but I don't see any failing task.

The broker node is called `celery@USER-vm` instead of `default`, so I don't know if that is affecting this.

my command to run celery is 
   `python manage.py celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO -B`

Any insight of where to look? MY best guess is that djcelery is not connected to rabbitmq, but not sure where to make those changes.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Settings.py

```
BROKER_URL="amqp://guest:guest@localhost//"
CELERY_BROKER_URL="amqp://guest:guest@localhost//"
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS=True
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY=8
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=None
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', 'application','msgpack', 'yaml']
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE='default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE='direct'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY='default'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=True
```

From celery.py

```
  from django.conf import settings
  os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','proj.settings')

  app = Celery('proj')

 app.conf.update(
   CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
  )

 app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS, related_name='tasks')
```

Comment: Hw did you configured BROKER_URL and RabbitMQ queues?

Comment: I updated post to show BROKER_URL. I configured RabbitMQ from Django. Is that necessary?